# How to share location preview on WhatsApp using Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-maps, geolocation, whatsapp

I am developing a WhatsApp bot using Node.js and (WATI API)[https://docs.wati.io/reference/introduction]. I need to send specific venue locations to users as a map preview and not a link on WhatsApp.

I am looking for an API or library that will help me encode the google map location or coordinate and send it as a small embedded map preview (image attached below) message on WhatsApp. Is there any way I can achieve this?

[image: Desried Result]   I

Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: I am not sure about WATI, but there is [location type message in WhatsApp business cloud api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages#location-messages).

Comment: But I need to send it from the same number as the other messages. I have not used WhatsApp business cloud API but I think it will be give me some other number

Comment: WATI is a BSP - Business service provider, which means they are using WhatsApp Business APIs, if you have registered your business and phone number with WATI, you have to ask them for this feature.

Comment: Oh ok, Yes, they provide a business number from their end so far they don't have this feature unlike Twilio so that's why I am looking for a library or other API that will help achieve this and send it from the same WhatsApp number.

Comment: This cloud API needs an access token/authentication token and business phone number id, i am not sure but you can get it from your business manager..

Comment: Yes, the WhatsApp Business API cloud provides a temporary access token, I am trying to figure out a way I can send messages from the existing WhatsApp number rather than using their Test number